# Backbonejs - How to filter a collection by multiple parameters?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a scenario where I need to filter a vehicle collection by multiple parameters - a series of radios, selectboxes etc that a user **may** choose to combine i.e. fuel, seats, color. Example combinations may be:

- color=red
- seats=4 & fuel=petrol
- fuel=diesel
- fuel=petrol & color=black & seats=2
- etc

It is simple enough to filter a collection by **one** parameter, but need some tips on multiple.

Here is my Vehicles collection:

```
  Vehicles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Vehicle,
        withFuelType: function(fuel) {
            return this.models.filter(function(vehicle) { return vehicle.get('fuel') === fuel; });
        },
        withSeats: function (seats) {
            return this.models.filter(function (vehicle) { return vehicle.get('seats') === seats; });
        },
        withColor: function(color) {
            return this.models.filter(function (vehicle) { return vehicle.get('color') === color; });
        }
    })
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) for simple equality searches:

> **where** `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed **attributes**. Useful for simple cases of `filter`.

So you don't need those functions, you can do this instead:

```
c.where({ fuel: 'petrol', color: 'black' });
c.where({ seats: 2 });
```

You should be able to turn your search query string into an object and hand that to `where` to get what you need.